# solve this linear partial differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I have this PDE:
$u_t + t u_x + u = 0.$ The initial condition is 
$$
u(0,x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
 1-x &\mbox{ if $0\leq x\leq 1$} \\
  0 &\mbox{ x > 1}
       \end{array} \right.
$$

The boundary condition is
$$
u(t,x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
 1-t &\mbox{ if $0\leq t \leq 1$} \\
  0 &\mbox{ t > 1}
       \end{array} \right.
$$

Here's what I have:

Solving for characteristics
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dt}{1} &= \frac{dx}{t} = \frac{du}{u}\\ \textrm{gives}\\ \frac{dt}{1} &= \frac{dx}{t} and \frac{dt}{1} = \frac{du}{u}
\end{align}
$$
Solving these two ODE's gives:
$$
x = t^2/2 + c_1 \textrm{ and } |u| = c_2 e^t
$$
Was that the right step? I'm not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that this is a **linear** PDE. So, using the **method of characteristics** we take:

$\dfrac{dt}{1}=\dfrac{dx}{t}\implies t dt = dx\implies  \dfrac{t^2}2=x+c_1\implies \boxed{c_1=\dfrac{t^2}2-x}$.

$\bullet$ We consider the following transform:

$\begin{array}{l}
\xi=\xi(x,t)=-x+\dfrac{t^2}2\\
\eta=\eta(x,t)=t
\end{array}$

We need to check the Jacobian determinant of the previous transform:

$J(\xi,\eta)=\begin{vmatrix} \dfrac{\partial \xi}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial \xi}{\partial t} \\ \dfrac{\partial \eta}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial \eta}{\partial t}\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} -1 & t \\ 0 &1 \end{vmatrix}=-1\neq 0$.

Then we have (application of chain rule):

$\begin{array}{l}
u_x=\xi_x\cdot \bar u_\xi+\eta_x \cdot \bar u_\eta=-\bar u_\xi\\
u_t=\xi_t\cdot \bar u_\xi+\eta_t\cdot \bar u_\eta=t\cdot \bar u_\xi+\bar u_\eta
\end{array}$

We plug $u_x,u_t$ into the initial PDE  and we take:

\begin{align}
&t \cdot \bar u_\xi +\bar u_\eta +t\cdot(-\bar u_\xi)+\bar u=0\\
&\bar u_\eta=-\bar u\\
&\bar u(\xi,\eta)=f(\xi)\cdot e^{-\eta}, 
\end{align}

hence:
\begin{align}
\boxed{\bar u(\xi,\eta)=u(x,t)=f\Big(-x+\dfrac{t^2}2\Big)\cdot e^{-t}}
\end{align}

The last step is to define the function f. We do so, using the boundary and the initial conditions.

Comment: Very nice solution Thanasissdr, congratulations!

Answer (score 1):

The solution for your PDE without the application of the initial and the boundary conditions is

$$u \left( x,t \right) =F \left( -2\,x+{t}^{2} \right) {{\rm e}^{-t}}+{
\it C}\,{{\rm e}^{-t}}
$$

where $F$ is an arbitrary function and $C$ is a constant.

Comment: Could you please show how you got that answer?

Comment: You have a wrong sign when you are using the characteristics method.  The correct is  $du/u = -1$ and then you have $u = Ce^{-t}$.  From other side you are obtaining $x = (t^2)/2 + c_1$, then the solution is $u=f(c_1)$ where $f$ is an arbitrary function. You have then $u = f(x-(t^2)/2)e^{-t}$.  Do you agree?

Comment: So why is the solution the sum of the solutions of the two ODE's?I'm new to PDE so please be patient. Thank you.